# Why spark sql skips milliseconds when we do casting

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
 I dont know why this spark sql skips the last 3 000s after that decimal point

    df = spark.sql("""
      select cast('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' as timestamp) as a  from dbo.products
      """)

  df.show(1,False)
```

This above query produces 1900-01-01 00:00:00
It somehow misses the last 3 zero after decimals

Expected  is

```
 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Can someone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when milliseconds are `.000` spark by default skips that part:

```py
>>> spark.sql("SELECT CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS TIMESTAMP)").show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------+
|CAST(1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 AS TIMESTAMP)|
+------------------------------------------+
|1900-01-01 00:00:00                       |
+------------------------------------------+
```

If you set milliseconds to, for example, `.999`, it'll be displayed:

```py
>>> spark.sql("SELECT CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00.999' AS TIMESTAMP)").show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------+
|CAST(1900-01-01 00:00:00.999 AS TIMESTAMP)|
+------------------------------------------+
|1900-01-01 00:00:00.999                   |
+------------------------------------------+
```

If you really need that part to be displayed, use [date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html):

```py
>>> df = spark.sql("SELECT CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS TIMESTAMP) datecol")
>>> df.select(F.date_format("datecol", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").alias("datecol")).show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------+
|datecol                |
+-----------------------+
|1900-01-01 00:00:00.000|
+-----------------------+
```